# TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator)) in react-sortablejs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sortablejs

I got this error when using react-sortablejs library. Before the incident, I was barely doing anything but running npm and yarn install.
The function the error points at:

```
function __read(o, n) {
    var m = typeof Symbol === "function" && o[Symbol.iterator];
    if (!m) return o;
    var i = m.call(o), r, ar = [], e;
    try {
        while ((n === void 0 || n-- > 0) && !(r = i.next()).done) ar.push(r.value);
    }
    catch (error) { e = { error: error }; }
    finally {
        try {
            if (r && !r.done && (m = i["return"])) m.call(i);
        }
        finally { if (e) throw e.error; }
    }
    return ar;
}
```

In my code I import the library:

```
import Sortable from 'react-sortablejs'
```

And use it to wrap an array of component:

```
<Sortable
   tag="div" // Defaults to "div"
   onChange={(order, sortable, evt) => {
       this.props.dispatch(updateQuestionOrder(evt.item.getAttribute('data-id'), evt.newIndex, evt.oldIndex))
            }}
         >
           {items}
</Sortable>
```

Note that items could be an empty array.
Please tell me what's wrong.

Comment: Please go and check what exactly causes the undefined issue, then fix it by initial a defined variable instead of the undefined one.

Comment: empty array is not undefined array. so while defining items array set the value of items array i.e. items = []. For testing hard coded values in items array with required values/objects and make it working

Comment: I'm trying to reinstall the library. It's been working fine for a while.
@Mukund actually I did. The items works just as expected when I bring it ouside.

Comment: It seems that our project doesn't work well with react-sortablejs latest version. I tried to downgrade it to the version we used before and it worked. Thanks guys!